# I am having problems in Email Clients software : Outlook and emClient?

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, crash, email-client

I am having a problem in using email clients like "eM Client" and "MS Outlook"

**My System:**

Processor: i5-6600 @3.3GHz

RAM: 8 GB

Type: 64 Bit

Windows 10 Pro version 1709 (OS Build 16299.15), Activated

**The problem in "OutLook":**

I have installed Outlook. It was working fine. But all of sudden it got ruined. Now when I try to launch this app, it just stays there loading itself. See the pic below:

[image]

It is Outlook 2016. The problem is I can't find it in add/remove programs in control panel. what can be done to rectify this problem? Installing window again is not the option for me. If install/uninstall of Outlook is required, do I have to uninstall/install whole MS OFFICE??

**The problem in "em Client":**

It was working fine before as well. I think it was an update or something. After that, it is giving me a headache. I have tried uninstalling/installing multiple times. Tried trial versions and the one I had already installed before. But the problem persists.

Problem is after it gets installed. Whenever I click somewhere on it (Launched eM Client), e.g. click on menu, click on settings, click on anywhere on the view, etc. it affects my system's display. I am using two LCD screens, so whenever it happens, one of the screen's resolution changes and sometimes the mouse pointer and Opened Apps on the screen shifts to other screens permanently.
After some clicks again, it returns the screen back. After removing this software from the system. Everything works fine.

Currently, I am using version 7.1.32772.0.

Kindly suggest anything to cater to these problems. I need to have one of these clients installed on my system preferably "eM Client".

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Outlook is installed by installing Office.

Comment: Yes.. OFFICE 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > The problem is I can't find it in add/remove programs in control panel.

How do you install Outlook? If it was installed via Windows Store, you will not see 
Office suit in Programs and Features. Please open Settings > Find Apps & features.

There are some common solutions to fix Outlook not openning.

1. Install the latest updates for Office
2. safe mode

Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

3. Create a new Outlook profile
4. Run the /resetnavpane command

Running the /resetnavpanecommand removes all customizations to the navigation pane.

•    Close Outlook.

•    Choose Start > Run.

•    In the Open box, type Outlook.exe /resetnavpane, and then choose OK.

Reference: https://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/outlookdoesntstart.htm